# hdf5 file opening error: "TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, hdf5, data-science

I've been trying to open up an existing .h5 data file in Python 2.7 under Spider. However, I kept getting this error with my code like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WtO0.png)

And the result is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Cl1.png)

Comment: Can you please post your code as txt and not as an image ? So it is easier for people helping you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to take the item with name "/train" of the class "file". The class "file" is not a Collection. I do not understand what you wanted to do at 6 line your code.
Maybe you meant

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

filename = 'train.h5'
# open file for Read/write
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r+')
# get group or dataset in h5 file
dataset = f["/train"]
```